# get error listen EADDRINUSE :::8080 after first successful server start

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash, express

Hi this problem just currently started happening and have never had this issue before. Every time I start up my express server it runs fine the first time. When I close the server in my git bash with control C it shuts down but when I try to start up the server again I get the EADDRINUSE error. This makes no sense at all and I have tried to use killall -9 node command without any success does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE error means that the port that your server is trying to use is already being used by something else. My suggestion would be to close all terminal windows first. Then start a completely new terminal window, and then try running the server. If that does not work, restart your laptop(I know this is tedious, but this usually works), and follow the above steps.

Comment: Ya I did that but still got the same error after restarting luckily I did find the issue. I believe I was starting up two servers at once and that was causing the issue for some reason I didn't have this issue until I upgraded node on my pc. Either way I did figure out the problem thank you for the help though much appreciated.